# Photograph of text looks blurry when small on website but when enlarged looks crisp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, png

I am editing some photos for a website that has text in it, when I upload them onto the site the text looks blurry, but when I pop the images open to being larger the text looks crisp and I am not sure why.

They are PNG since they are not clean lines on the edge so I need some transparency on the edges.
[image: smaller :blurry" text]

Has this happened to anyone? or does anyone have any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: It might just be because the browser uses a quick downscaling method. Have you tried in different browsers?

Comment: I usually use chrome, but tried on safari and it looked the same

Comment: Try Firefox and maybe Edge also. I think Safari uses the same downscale algorithm as Chrome.

Comment: yea but the prob is a majority of people will use chrome or safari so I need it to work on them as well

Answer (score 2):

The image appears to have been scaled down, or you are not viewing it at 100%.  Check the zoom level in Photoshop, and set it to 100%. That may be enough to fix it.

If you need to scale the image smaller to fit in another image, or to make a smaller image for a website, then in Preferences > General tab, set the image interpolation to "Bicubic Sharper (best for reduction)".

Copy and Paste the image, then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and scale the image.

The result is better

[image]

Comment: Both of these images are from when I uploaded the image onto the website, same file, just one is the basic view on the site and the other is when you pop the image out to view larger

Comment: @HannahBaker Then that means they are not the same zoom level. You can't compare images that are shown at different zoom levels.

Comment: so to adjust the image to make it more sharp for the smaller size you would suggest using the "Bicubic Sharper (best for reduction)".

Comment: I have just never experienced when an image is smaller it is less sharp, that has only happened to me when you view the image larger

Comment: Yes, rescale if you want a smaller image for a web page.  Don't scale images in a browser, they always look like crap - whether you make them bigger or smaller

Answer (score 1):

### Resize Images to Fit Webpage

Resize your images to fit the webpage without needing to be zoomed.

If using Photoshop, choose `Preserve Details` as the `resample` option when exporting - for a clean look with less loss of image quality.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but the image still seems to be "blurry" when i view it on the website, I hate to even call it blurry, it is almost like the contrast is strange, But I've tested it with multiple contrast and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Do you have the webpage URL so I can check it out?

Comment: https://celestekrishna.com/preludered/#libretto the pages of the libretto come up randomly, but I have inputted 3 different versions of "call up the devil" the two that are next to each other are the ones that I am testing, As you can see the rest of the images when you pop them out they become blurry. That is what we are trying to fic if that amkes any sense.

Comment: also trying it with this page https://celestekrishna.com/preludered/#notes and the music square on this page is doing the same thing

Comment: @HannahBaker that web page is rescaling the image, so the problem is with the site, not Photoshop.

Comment: @HannahBaker. This is your image. https://celestekrishna.com/static/public/uploads/CELESTE_BOOKLET_051_tested.png It is too big for the page and is being rescaled by the browser, which is why it doesn't look right. This can not be avoided because there are many different screen sizes, but you can get it looking good on most peoples devices. What you should do, is design your image size for the most popular screen size of your target audience.

Comment: You can get this info from Google Analytics if a site has been running for a while. The most popular screen size varies from country to country, so if you're audience is mostly in the USA, use the size best suited for that location. You can find this info here: http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/all/united-states-of-america

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the reason why your image look strange.

It seems to come from the css styling the *fotorama* library uses.

Here is the image as it is now on the web page:

[image]

If I turn on *Developer Tools* and select the parent element of the image, i notice that it has the *transform* attribute set to *translateZ(0)*.

[image]

If I turn of this setting the image looks good:

[image]

[image]

So my advice is to either stop using *fotorama*, or change the code, so it doesn't add  that attribute.

Comment: The font is part of an image, not the website as such. https://celestekrishna.com/static/public/uploads/CELESTE_BOOKLET_051_tested.png

Comment: thank you so much for looking into this. When I turned that off in the developer mood it changed the image. THanks!

Comment: Good to hear! Please remember to accept the answer so others can benefit from it.